How can I direct a SwiftUI parent view to have its embedded child view persist its values independently?
I have a View that is composed with a child view that is vended from a user selected object, presented as a sheet in a containing view.  The Title/Address/Port in the screen shot below is from a single view and then the parent view has the Ok/Cancel buttons (The reasons for them to be separate is that I will need to reuse the vended settings views in another context which will have other settings and will have its own buttons)

I simply want the behavior that if the user presses cancel all edits are abandoned, and if the user presses Ok the values are persisted.  Essentially in the child view I have:
@ObservedObject viewModel: ViewModel
@State addressEditValue: String
@State portEditValue: String

var body : some View {
  VStack {
    Text("Enter the server address and port")
      .font(.title)
    HStack {
      Text("Address:")
      TextField("Address", text: $addressEditValue)
       .textContentType(.URL)
      Text("Port:")
      TextField("Port", value: $portEditValue, formatter: NumberFormatter())
    }
  }
  .onAppear {
    addressEditValue = viewModel.address
    portEditValue = viewModel.port
  }
}

In the container view I have:
.sheet(isPresented: $isSettingsSheetPresented, content: {
  VStack {
    ChildView
    HStack {
      Spacer()
      Button {
      isTimingSettingsPresented.toggle()
      } label: {
        Text("Cancel")
      }
      Button {
        // instruct child view to persist itself here
        isTimingSettingsPresented.toggle()
      } label: {
        Text("Ok")
      }
      .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
    }
  }
})

I've tried having the Child view conform to a protocol with a Submit function, but I only seem to be able to vend the settings view as an AnyView, which is type erasing the view.  When I attempt to cast the view, it always fails:
if let childView = ChildView as? SubmittableViewProtocol

I've also tried to use published variables between the two views and respond to their onChange modifiers, but the 'work' I need to do once its submitted ends up called before the onChange is responded to.
This seems like it should be a simple thing to abandon or persist changes for a settings sheet in SwiftUI, but alas I'm out of ideas.  Am I missing something obvious and simple here?  Its very possible I'm not thinking a reactive way here, so any help is appreciated.

Can you show a [mcve] of the current behaviour of your code? From what you have shown here, it seems like you have a very wrong mindset when using SwiftUI.

There has to be some connection from the child to the parent, it could be a Bool that says isSaving.

Change the view model property modifier to use a binding(@Binding viewModel: ViewModel) and pass the view model in from the presenting view.  If the 'ok' button is tapped update the view model's address and port values with the value from their respective textfields, if 'cancel' is tapped then you don't modify the view model's properties
